# Insert an element to AdjacencyGraph

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I'm not able to insert an element to mine AdjacencyGraph.
I suppose that i should modify my AdjcencyMatrix:

```
Matrix = IncidenceMatrix[Import["C:\\Users\\Network.net"]];
Length[Matrix]
356  (*So I've 356 nodes*)
Matrix1 = Insert[Matrix, Insert[Table[0*i, {i, 1, 357, 1}], 1, {{356}, {357}}], 357]; (*I want to add the 357th node*) 
AdjacencyGraph[Matrix1]
```

But it doesn't work. Some help?

Comment: Can you adapt this? Matrix = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}; Print[AdjacencyGraph[Matrix]]; Matrix = Map[Join[#, {0}] &, Matrix]; Matrix = Insert[Matrix, {1, 1, 1, 0}, -1];
Print[AdjacencyGraph[Matrix]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`EdgeAdd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeAdd.html) and/or [`VertexAdd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexAdd.html).

For example:

```
am1 = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}};
ag1 = AdjacencyGraph[am1, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
ag2 = EdgeAdd[ag1, 2 <-> 4]
```

[image]

```
AdjacencyMatrix[ag1] // Normal
(* {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}} *)

AdjacencyMatrix[ag2] // Normal
(* {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Example 2:

```
Show[ag3 = EdgeAdd[ag1, {1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 4}],
 PlotLabel -> MatrixForm[AdjacencyMatrix[ag3]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a purely matrix-based approach, you can try:

```
m = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}};
AdjacencyGraph[m, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

ADD = {1, 2};
VADD = 0 Range[Length[m]];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ADD], i++, VADD[[i]] = 1];
m = Append[m, VADD];
VADD = Append[VADD, 0];
m = Transpose[Append[Transpose[m], VADD]]
AdjacencyGraph[m, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

You simply adjust `m` to be your actual adjacency matrix and `ADD` to be the vertices to which the new vertex should be added.

This is sloppy code, but it gets the job done that way.

Are you using sparse matrices? This should work even if `m` is sparse, I think.